# Send Esc key in KDE 4?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I am trying to set up a custom shortcut to map Esc to Esc:Esc, i.e. simulate a double press on Esc key, and so far have had no luck.
(systemsettings -> gestures and shortcuts -> custom shortcuts)

I also tried Escape:Escape, didn't work either.

It would be better to have a comprehensive list of how every key should be represented.

Comment: So you're trying to execute a double Esc every time the Esc key is pressed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am using the jVi plugin in netbeans, and i need to type esc twice to exit the code-asistance popup, which is annoying.